# Accessing Microsoft Exchange using Java - any better APIs

Tags: java, webservice-client, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I have a requirement to access Exchange Server(2003, 2007) to send and receive mail, contacts, folders and calendar using Java API.

Exchange Server 2010 supports this with Java webservices, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/12/14/exchange-web-services-java-api-1-1-is-now-available-yes-that-s-right-java.aspx

I found J-Integra-Exchange seems like promising solution. However, I have never worked with it. Did any body worked with J-Integra-Exchange?, can you recommend this or any other better API?

Answer (score 0):

2007 SP1 is supported by the Microsoft EWS API.  For anyone pre 2007 SP1, you're kind of on your own.  I was looking into J-Interop originally for that, but we ended up updating our Exchange anyways, so I just used EWS.  Not a good thing to be sitting all the way back on Exchange 2003 these days...  That's 11 (soon to be 12) years ago...  :-)